# Sort output of let or set

Tags: variables, sort, environment-variables

How to sort the output of let or get? E.g., I want to sort all global variables containing "python":

```
:filter python let g:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can capture output with `execute()` function and then pump it through `sort()`. The whole command could be then:

   ```
   command! -bang -nargs=1 -complete=command Sorted
       \ echo join(sort(split(execute(<q-mods> . ' ' . <q-args>), "\n"),
           \ {s1, s2 -> <bang>(s1 ># s2) - <bang>(s1 <# s2)}), "\n")
   ```

Now you can do `:Sorted filter python let g:`

2. If it makes sense to create a more flexible solution, you can capture command output *into a temporary buffer* instead. And once it's in a buffer, `:sort`-ing (or any other kind of processing) becomes easy.

   ```
   nnoremap <silent><leader>x :put =trim(execute(input(':', '', 'command')))<CR>
   ```

Now press `<leader>x` and enter your command. When the output gets into a buffer you can `:sort` it as usual.

Comment: I wonder why vim does not have a built-in solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach. `:filter let` will only look for matching variable names, so you can re-implement it using `filter()` function and sort the resulting dict and output all matches afterwards. This is using the new method functionality of Vim 8.1 and a lambda expression.

```
for val in sort(keys((copy(g:)->filter({k -> k =~# 'python'}))))|echo printf("%s: %s", val, g:[val])|endfor
```

Note: we are `copy()`ing the global dict first, because `filter()` filters the given dictionary in place, which we do not want here.

Comment: FYI, that command gives me multiple errors (Vim 8.1.1772): E731 (using dictionary as string), 2 x E116 (invalid args). I'm able to run with one less lambda, i.e iterate over `sort(keys(filter(copy(g:), {k -> k =~# 'python'})))`. (Oh, and it appears you have a superfluous pair of parens in there.)

Comment: yes, please update your vim. The latest patch that mentions methods is 8.1.2013

Comment: Got it. Thanks.