# Redirect output of vim command into the vim buffer

Tags: vimrc

To read a file into the vim buffer I can do something like:

```
:r myfile.txt
```

Or to grab a command's output:

```
:r !ls
```

Is there a way to run a vim command and get the output to where my cursor is? something like:

```
:r nmap
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort output of let or set](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22073/sort-output-of-let-or-set)

Comment: @Matt not really. I was able to find something using something like `:r|put=execute('nmap')`. How could that be done with `:silent` too?

Comment: `:silent put =execute('nmap')`

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13172/10604